# Matlab: Flipping image coordinates to cartesian coordinates

Tags: image, matlab, coordinates, cartesian

I am new to Matlab. I have an image (the size is mxnx3) with a few human-selected points on the image. For example:

```
p1 = [267,79];

p2 = [96,372];
```

These points are image coordinates with (1,1) at the top left. I'm trying to convert this to Cartesian coordinates with (0,0) on the bottom left. How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to directly translate your co-ordinates in code, you could make a simple anonymous function:

```
img2cart = @(p) [p(1), img.size(2) - p(2)];
q1 = img2cart(p1);
q2 = img2cart(p2);
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm a beginner! I'm still confused by the function. Can you please explain:[p(1), img.size(2) - p(2)]?? Thanks!

Comment: If i understand correctly, this means that the original image x is used as the cartesian x. then the y value is determined by subtracting y from the number of image rows.

Comment: Yep, you've got it.  Also, because `img` is not a parameter to the function, its current value at the time the function was created is sort of "burned-in" to the function.  If you want something more general, define the function with `@(p,img)` *ie* pass `img` as the second parameter whenever you call it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly: just use

```
axis xy
```

From [`axis` doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/axis.html):

> AXIS XY  puts MATLAB into its default "Cartesian" axes mode.  The
>          coordinate system origin is at the lower left corner.  The x
>          axis is horizontal and is numbered from left to right.  The y
>          axis is vertical and is numbered from bottom to top.

Comment: Definitely the right way to flip the axes, but I don't understand the (1,1) -> (0,0) thing in the question.  I guess that's a typo?

Comment: not a typo! i'm studying this webpage for 2d rigid registration, but i'm not understanding the code for flipping the coordinates: http://dominionsw.com/wordpress/?p=111